# How to specify the type of the observable in angular

Tags: angular, types

```
getEmployeeData(): Observable<any> {}
```

Here observable type is "any". But here I need to specify the type of the observable instead of any. At what basis I need to specify the observable type. Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: You can create your own type using interface and then apply it to `Observable<myType>;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class which have properties of whatever data you are expecting from the `getEmployeeData` service for Example

```
getEmployeeData(): Observable<IEmployeeData> {}

    export class EmployeeData implements IEmployeeData{
    constructor(
    public id:number
    )
    }
    
    export interface IEmployeeData{
    public id:number;
    }
```